# Can’t loop value in html table

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I’m building a function which can let admin to delete account in that page.

I have several accounts in admin page but all the delete buttons are holding a value from first account in that page instead of other account.

```
<form action="/admin" method="post">
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr style="background-color:burlywood"> 
        <td><input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{user.username}}">{{user.username}}</td>
        <td><input type="submit" for="user" value="Delete"></td>
    {% endfor %}  
    </tr>   
       
</table>
```

```
@app.route("/admin", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def admin():
"""Manage account"""
if request.method == "GET":
    user_id = session["user_id"] 
    admin = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = (?)", 
user_id)

    for row in admin:
        if int(row["id"]) == 17:
            users = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users")
            return render_template("admin.html", users = users)

        else:    
            return apology("Only Admin can access this page!")
    return apology("valid return")

else:
    username = request.form.get("user")
    flash(f"{username} has been deleted!")
    return redirect("/")
```

I expected each delete button is holding each value in column.

After the issue is fixed, when delete button is clicked flash function will show the different username based on the value not admin at all.

[here is html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkv7i.jpg)

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, share your code here

Comment: Please, post your code as text and not as pictures (let alone photos of the screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tags I believe you're using Jinja to load and render the html page, however, you should be more clear about what you want to ask. 
This may sound like a bad idea and definitely something you shouldn't do in production but how about creating different forms for each user?
Something like this :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for user in users %}
    <form action="/admin" method="post">
        <tr style="background-color:burlywood"> 
             <td><input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{user.username}}">{{user.username}}</td>
             <td><input type="submit" for="user" value="Delete"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>   
    {% endfor %}   
</table>
```

Comment: It's works! thanks for your help and I'm really appreciate it! Btw I am a student and still exploring in coding :) I understand the logic and overall the idea how the program should run like... just somehow I don't understand about the "rules" like the answer you given just now which I should loop the form as well :(

Comment: Hi, sorry for disturb. I would like to get some advise from you since you have working experiences. I am curious what is the meaning of "shouldn't do in production". Is my design too simple or I might use a framework to design the file or something else? And what's the way that I can improve my code to become more useful in future production. Your advise will be highly appreciated! Hope to get your reply soon

Comment: Hey @DarrenWong , there aren't any generalized rules that a production code must follow, although many big tech companies do enforce certain rules in the development of their production build. Mostly, the aim of any such rule is to keep the code simple and easy to maintain as most programmers switch jobs at some point of time. And about using loop to render the form multiple times, it is always better to keep the code as static as possible whenever you get the chance.

Comment: For example in your case, wouldn't it be better if you just replaced the multiple submit buttons with maybe a single button and a checklist? The admin could select the users whose account is due for deletion and use a single button to delete the selected users. Such design would be both user-friendly and would prevent you from rendering so many unnecessary forms and buttons.

Comment: I think I got some point from you. I’ll take note of this for improve my code in future project. For your meaning here is I need to design my website in better and more friendly user way if I want to use it in production? Besides that, I need to keep my code as simple as possible instead of my case like if got thousand users then my code need to loop thousand forms and buttons…. Am I getting the right point?

Comment: Yes thats right.

Answer (score 0):

I think your line only returns usernames in your users variable:
users = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users")

So users in your template is an array that only contains a list of names, or only contains one name.

1 / Whats contains users?

2 / what if you put {{ user }} instead of {{ user.username }} in your template?

Comment: Yes, `users` is a list of names. I used jinja loop to show each username in `users`. If I put {{user}} then result will be `username: admin`.